# ProducerTemplate unable to sendBody to Direct Endpoint

Tags: java, apache-camel

I would like to use Camel as an integration point for an application I am developing.  My intention is to, from my application, inject messages into camel as well as receive messages from camel and through a camel context route what to do with those messages at application launch.  From the research I've done it would appear that ProducerTemplate / ConsumerTemplate is the way to communicate with the routes defined within a camel context.  However, when I publish to 'direct:connect' using ProducerTemplate I receive a 'No consumers available' exception.  This occurs even though route1 is able to communicate with route2 and I receive a log message stating:

```
Route: route2 started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://connect]
```

Can anyone please provide guidance on how to best use Camel for my purposes?

#### CamelEval.java

```
public class CamelEval {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {      
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ("camel-streams.xml");
        SpringCamelContext sctx = new SpringCamelContext (ctx);
        sctx.start();

        sctx.createProducerTemplate().sendBody("direct:connect", "hello world");

        Thread.sleep (5000);
    }
}
```

#### camel-streams.xml

```
<camelContext trace="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="stream:in?promptMessage=Enter Something: "/>
        <transform>
            <simple>${body.toUpperCase()}</simple>
        </transform>
        <to uri="direct:connect"/>
    </route>
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:connect"/>
        <to uri="stream:out"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You end up with 2 Camel's. There is already one defined in the XML file.

What you should do is to ask Spring to give you that Camel from the xml file, instead of creating a new Camel using the code

```
new SpringCamelContext
```

The easiest is to give the camelContext and id in the XML file

```
<camelContext id="myCamel" ...>
```

, and then use the spring api to lookup the bean with that id

```
CamelContext sctx = (CamelContext) cxt.getBean("myCamel");
```

Comment: Of course, explained its actually pretty obvious I suppose, thank you so much!